# Using Circles instead of Markers in Google Maps API

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, marker

I'm using the Google Maps Android API to display Markers on a map. My markers are basically two circles (inner solid circle with slightly transparent outer circles that adjust according to the zoom level of the map). Since my total number of markers has grown to 1000-2000 markers my app has problems with lagging. Clustering is not an option according to the specs.

I got some feedback at Google I/O 18 by Ankur from the Google Maps API Team. I should use circles instead of drawables for my markers.

I am adding and creating the circles like this:

```
private var selectedPoi: Poi? = null

fun addCircles(pois: List<Poi>) {
    pois.forEach { poi ->
        val zoomLevel = map.cameraPosition.zoom.toDouble()
        val isSelected = selectedPoi?.id == poi.id
        val innerCircleOptions = circleOptionsProvider.getInnerCircleOptions(poi, markersVisible, isSelected)
        val outerCircleOptions = circleOptionsProvider.getOuterCircleOptions(poi, zoomLevel, markersVisible, isSelected)
        map.addCircle(innerCircleOptions).apply { tag = poi }
        map.addCircle(outerCircleOptions).apply { tag = poi }
    }
}

fun getInnerCircleOptions(poi: Poi, markersVisible: Boolean, isSelected: Boolean): CircleOptions =
    CircleOptions()
        .fillColor(colorForPoi(poi, isSelected))
        .strokeWidth(0f)
        .zIndex(if (isSelected) INNER_CIRCLE_SELECTED_Z_INDEX else INNER_CIRCLE_Z_INDEX)
        .center(poi.location.toLatLng())
        .radius(5.0)
        .visible(markersVisible)
        .clickable(!isSelected)

fun getOuterCircleOptions(poi: Poi, zoomLevel: Double, markersVisible: Boolean, isSelected: Boolean): CircleOptions =
    CircleOptions()
        .fillColor(if (isSelected) context.color(R.color.colorPrimary) else context.color(R.color.black_30))
        .strokeWidth(0f)
        .zIndex(if (isSelected) OUTER_CIRCLE_SELECTED_Z_INDEX else OUTER_CIRCLE_Z_INDEX)
        .center(poi.location.toLatLng())
        .radius(radiusForZoomLevel(zoomLevel, isSelected))
        .visible(markersVisible)
        .clickable(!isSelected)
```

**First problem:** the lagging got worse.

**Second problem:** I can't set a minimum or maximum size for the circles because they use a radius to adjust the size on the map. (zooming in or out let the circles appear very very small/big)

Does anyone have experience with this or uses circles as a replacement for markers without lagging?

Thanks in advance.